# How to write csv file row by row in python?

Tags: python, csv

I want to write a csv file `userperday.csv` row by row with a loop. I have a list `dates` with dates and I want to check if they are in the second list `dates2`. I tried with the code below

```
with open('userperday.csv', "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for j in dates:
        n=0
        if j in dates2:
            n+=1
        rows=zip(j, n)
        for row in rows:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

My expected output is a csv file with two columns and in the first columns there a the dates from the list `dates` and in the second column should be a 1 or a 0, so if the particular date is in `dates2`or not. In addition I wisch to have a header.

Comment: Instead of doing `zip(j, n)`, have you tried to instead just make a list literal? e.g. `[j, n]`?

Comment: My j is a datetime.date object and so I become the error: iterable expected, not datetime.date

Comment: Because when you do [`zip(j, n)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), those aren't iterables. It would be sort of like doing `for x in j:; for y in n:`, neither of which make sense, nor are they valid statements, because there's nothing to iterate over

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that you continue to increment n, but don't set it back to zero after a match is found. For this kind of problem I would use a dictionary to keep track of the counts.

```
with open('userperday.csv',"w") as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  rows = {}

  for j in dates:
      rows[j] = 0
      if j in dates2:
          rows[j] += 1

  #Fill in the header
  writer.writerow(["Date","Counts"])

  # Iterate through dict to get date and counts
  for key,val in rows.items():
      writer.writerow([key,val])
```